# Rvm wrapper doesn't work when using another gemset

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemset

I am creating a rvm wrapper (`ftg` is the ruby program I wrote):

```
$> rvm gemset create ftg_gemset
ruby-2.2.3 - gemset created /Users/pinouchon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@ftg_gemset

$> rvm wrapper ruby-2.2.3@ftg_gemset ftg
Regenerating ruby-2.2.3@ftg_gemset wrappers........

$> which ftg
/Users/pinouchon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@ftg/bin/ftg

$> ftg # command is found. Very cool
Usage: ftg <command> [arguments...]
...
```

So far so good. But then:

```
$> rvm gemset use global
Using ruby-2.2.3 with gemset global

$> ftg # command not found. Not cool
zsh: command not found: ftg
```

I thought rvm wrappers were supposed to allow you to wrap a ruby program as an "executable", and execute if from anywhere (regardless of your current path or gemset). Am I understanding rvm wrappers correctly ?

Comment: you probably want a scope when you create the wrapper "rvm wrapper ruby-2.2.3@ftg_gemset run ftg". after that try running run_ftg

Comment: @Mircea Good idea. I tried `rvm wrapper ruby-2.2.3@ftg_gemset run_ftg`.
Then move to other gemset, `run_ftg`, and I get `/Users/pinouchon/.rvm/bin/run_ftg: line 7: exec: ftg: not found`

Comment: **rvm wrapper ruby-2.2.3@ftg_gemset run ftg** without the _ between run and  ftg and after that you do run_ftg